# What determines whether or not there's overtime?

Tags: team-fortress-2

In TF2, in the Domination Control Point mode, there's sometimes overtime, which  (to my frustration) can last from a couple of seconds to a good few minutes.

My question is

> What determines whether there is overtime (or is it random?) and what determines how long it lasts?

Comment: I don't think you actually mean "Domination Control Point", as overtime does not occur in that mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Domination Control Point? Do you mean King of the Hill?

If so, overtime will last until the point is "uncontested" and the owning team is at 0:00. That means, if people of the opposing team are still on the control point even if you are at 0 seconds and own the point, there will be overtime. Even if they are not, if the point is still "partially captured" by the opposing team, overtime will last until this has been cleared completely (which will happen faster than usual).